# Long rows get split while writing in csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am using the following code to write a csv file in python:

```
with open('..\Test.csv', 'w', newline='') as dest:
    writer = csv.writer(dest,dialect='excel')
    # header line
    writer.writerow(['ImageId', 'Class', 'WKT'])
    writer.writerow([image_name, int(c), prediction])
```

The problem in this case is the variable prediction contains a large string containing words and special characters, as a result of which the entire row gets truncated at some point and starts from a new row in the csv format. The new row contains a double quote at the end as well as now each word in the second row is entered into separate columns.

Can someone please suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It sounds like `prediction` contains a newline character, which gets written out to the file. That should be OK if the `dialect` you specify to the `csv.writer` is correct. It will escape or quote each field in such a way that another program can correctly read it without getting confused by the extra newlines. It's not clear exactly what's wrong with the output, so I'm not sure how we can help you.

Comment: I feel that prediction contains characters which need to be escaped. Please provide some sample output for more help.

Comment: so the prediction contains as follows:
MULTIPOLYGON (((0.0091065209850000 -0.0047031504000000, 0.0091754054100000 -0.0049202188800000, 0.0091754054100000 -0.0047031504000000, 0.0091065209850000 -0.0047031504000000)))

I edited this value as its too big to fit. Deleted some numbers in between

Comment: Is there any way to increase the size limit of one cell of a csv file ? I noticed that the split just occurred in the middle of a number in the prediction value

Comment: The `csv` module isn't going to insert random extra newlines, that newline must have been in your data already. You should figure out where that data is coming from and fix it there.

Comment: That is what I have been trying to do. But I was curious if this has anything to do with the cell size, because for less values, it is working fine.

Comment: Based on the value of `prediction` you have given, what would the resulting CSV file need to look like? I suggest you edit the question to include these details.